# Pick column values based upon the priority in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows

```
ID  COL2        COL3    date
1   CLINICAL    red     30-Aug
1   HOUSE CALLS green   27-Oct
1   PREDICTIVE  blue    29-Oct
1   CLINICAL    green   30-oct
2   PREDICTIVE  green   20-Jan
2   CLINICAL    blue    21-Jan
2   HOUSE CALLS red     20-Feb
2   PREDICTIVE  green   28-Feb
3   HOUSE CALLS red     30-Apr
3   PREDICTIVE  green   12-May
4   CLINICAL    blue    14-May
```

I have to create an additional column COL4 which will pick values from COL3 based upon the values in COL2 per ID. COL2 can only have 3 values

CLINICAL(1st priority)
PREDICTIVE(2nd priority)
HOUSE CALLS(3rd priority)

Output should look like this:

```
ID  COL2        COL3    date    COl4
1   CLINICAL    red     30-Aug  red
1   HOUSE CALLS green   27-Oct  red
1   PREDICTIVE  blue    29-Oct  red
1   CLINICAL    green   30-oct  green
2   PREDICTIVE  green   20-Jan  green
2   CLINICAL    blue    21-Jan  blue
2   HOUSE CALLS red     20-Feb  blue
2   PREDICTIVE  green   28-Feb  blue
3   HOUSE CALLS red     30-Apr  red
3   PREDICTIVE  green   12-May  green
4   CLINICAL    blue    14-May  blue
```

For example lets take ID '1'. In the first table col2 value is clinical on 30-aug and it also have highest priority so the value of col4 will remain same for ID 1 till 29oct bcz on 30th Clinical again comes so value should be changed to green. Lets take ID '2' for this first value that came for col2 is predictive so the value of col4 will be its corresponding col3 value. But after that on 21st col2 value changed to clinical which of highest priority so col4 value will be changed to blue. Same as follows for other ID based in Priority of values present in col2.

This is the query I am currently using but when for id 1 when Clinical is coming again with some another col3 value then its still picking the older one
i.e red but it should pick green for 4th row

```
COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN [col2] = 'CLINICAL' THEN col3 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date ),
                MAX(CASE WHEN [col2] = 'PREDICTIVE MODEL' THEN col3 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date),
                MAX(CASE WHEN [col2] = 'HOUSECALLS' THEN col3 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date )
   ) as BANNER_RISK_LEVEL
```

Comment: Do you have any column for ORDER BY? Dates are belongs to different years(seems) and with out YEAR value. Order by Date column will give unexpected data.

Comment: in my example dates are in sequential order only

Comment: you have 20-Jan after 30-oct. Both belongs to same year?

Comment: Yes all belongs to same year this is just an example that we will start calculating col4 value based upon date column

Comment: Can you define a column for ORDER your data initially?

Comment: first id then date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this below option.

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9591b2a33f539be2d97779494ea30180)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID,CAST(Date+'-2019' AS DATE)) RN
    FROM your_table
)

SELECT ID,COL2,COL3,date,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 COL3 
    FROM CTE B 
    WHERE B.RN <= A.RN  
    AND B.ID = A.ID 
    ORDER BY (CASE WHEN B.COL2 = 'CLINICAL' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), 
    B.RN DESC
) Col4
FROM CTE A
```

Comment: @Gauravsingh You are most welcome. Its nice to hear that the code worked :)

Answer (score 1):

This may be simplest using `apply`:

```
select t.*, tt.col3              
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.id = t.id
      order by (case when col2 = 'CLINICAL' then 1
                     when col2 = 'PREDICTIVE' then 2
                     else 3
                end),
               date desc
     ) tt;
```

Comment: Its giving me the most recent col3 value in every row where col2 is clinical. I want it to change based on priority

Comment: Hi Gordon,Can you look in my current Code and see if any changes can be done to make it work. It working fine just that when clinical is coming again it picking the old clinical value only not the latest one

Comment: @Gauravsingh . . . Based on your priorities, that is how I understand the question.